# matplotlib can't open *.jpg file

Tags: python, matplotlib, operating-system, python-imaging-library

I have *.jpg images in a directory "dogs" and I can access the first one as below:

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.expanduser('~/fastai/data/dogscats'))
cwd=os.getcwd()
dog=os.listdir(os.path.join(cwd,'valid/dogs'))[0]
print (dog)

dog.5535.jpg
```

the problem is when I try to plot the image with matplotlib it can't 
locate the image:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imread(dog)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dog.5535.jpg'
```

I tried opening the dog with pillow but it gives the same error.

however, I can read 'dog.5535.jpg' if I place the image on my desktop and give that path to `plt.imread()`.  Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: There may be issues with the dots in your file name, have you tried opening a file without a dot, or with the dot replaced with an underscore? And are you running the second script from the same place as the first?

Comment: @g-anderson-I tried replacing 'dog.; in my file name with '' but the error remained the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From these lines:

```
dog=os.listdir(os.path.join(cwd,'valid/dogs'))[0]
print (dog)
#OUT: dog.5535.jpg
```

it looks like there is a file `dog.5535.jpg` with the complete relative path (w.r.t. current working directory) is `valid/dogs/dog.5535.jpg`. However, the `dog` variable does only contain the filename. Therefore when you try

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imread(dog)
```

It looks for `dog.5535.jpg` in your current working directory, where the file is not. Coming from the cwd, you still have to add the rest of the path:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imread(dog)
os.path.join('valid', 'dogs', dog)
#or os.path.join(cwd, 'valid', 'dogs', dog)
```

Note that I also changed the `valid/dogs` part in the path.join function, as specifying path seperators in an argument to `path.join` kind of beats the point of using `path.join`

Comment: @FlyingTeller-Thanks